# Java8 won't install - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, java

The following is the complete error message:

```
$ sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java8-set-default
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho | ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/46.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 237 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
(Reading database ... 209311 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u144-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Unpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-10-19 10:54:20--  XXXXXXdownload.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.73.180.74, 23.73.180.26
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.73.180.74|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: XXXXXXXedelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-10-19 10:54:20--  XXXXXXXXXedelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.6.18.58, 2600:1408:10:297::2d3e, 2600:1408:10:286::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.6.18.58|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: XXXXXXXXdownload.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508424980_f583c63a4509f58dff79754a871c4730 [following]
--2017-10-19 10:54:20--  XXXXXXXXdownload.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508424980_f583c63a4509f58dff79754a871c4730
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.73.180.74|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-19 10:54:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

(Note: I had to replace the http stuff with X's)

Answer (score 0):

Note the error when `apt-get` tries to install the software.

```
ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Oracle has moved the JDK 8 download page to the Java Archive and the installer does not work. Probably, the [webup8 repository](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) may be fixed in the future

**Workarounds**

You may

- Download the self-extracting installer from the [Archive Page for Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html) and run that files, or
- Install Java 9 instead.

---

**NOTE:**  Oracle has published notes about the [End of Life (EOL) of Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html). Public updates notifications have ended and the updates will end at September of 2018.